# Strange file in ec2 instance

Tags: python, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

I deploy my models on ec2. After a while, I got strange join attempts:

```
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 17/17] 3.0.182.215 () {40 vars in 608 bytes} [Sat Jan 23 19:36:40 2021] POST / => generated 178 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 405) 3 headers in 123 bytes 
(1 switches on core 0)
15.207.221.143 - - [23/Jan/2021:19:44:27 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 18/18] 15.207.221.143 () {36 vars in 504 bytes} [Sat Jan 23 19:44:27 2021] GET /.env => generated 232 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 87 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
15.207.221.143 - - [23/Jan/2021:19:44:27 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 178 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36" "-"
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 19/19] 15.207.221.143 () {40 vars in 611 bytes} [Sat Jan 23 19:44:27 2021] POST / => generated 178 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 405) 3 headers in 123 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
102.165.30.37 - - [23/Jan/2021:19:45:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 225 "-" "NetSystemsResearch studies the availability of various services across the internet. Our website is netsystemsresearch.com" "-"
```

And 3 files appeared in the root folder:

```
core.10 core.19 core.29
```

When I trying to apply `cat` or `git add .` i get `Permission denied`. But i can remove this file.

My app build on tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-docker

Full code here: https://github.com/Tayge/demonstration_models

What are these files, connections? Is it dangerous? Thank you in advance!

Comment: This would not be related to the fact that the virtual machine is running on Amazon EC2 because it is within the OS / Disk.

Comment: It looks like your system is accepting connections from the public Internet, and it's being attacked (not necessarily in a directed way, it just happens).  At the very least there's some sort of bug causing some server or other process to crash.  You might want to destroy this EC2 instance and recreate it on a VPC with a little more isolation.